# How to show the "Design" category in a custom CollectionEditor when overriding CreateInstance()?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, custom-controls

If I comment out `CreateInstance`, then the "Design" is showing; but if I override it, it is not showing. How can I make it shown?

No override:

[image]

Override:

[image]

Code:

```
public class MyEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public MyEditor(Type type) : base(type)
    {
    }

    protected override Type[] CreateNewItemTypes()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            typeof(TabPage) //TabPage is a subclass of "Panel".
        };
    }
    protected override object CreateInstance(Type itemType)
    {
        var item = new TabPage(true);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Also, the title of the collection editor window is "Object Collection Editor", instead of my collection's name such as "TabPage Collection Editor". Not a big problem, but I would like to fix this, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

With the lack of examples, I resorted to decompiling the .NET Framework and seeing how Microsoft did it. Microsoft's `TabPageCollectionEditor` was inside "System.Design.dll". It was using the `base`'s `CreateInstance` and then adding modifying the result.

So I changed my code like the following and it works now. The reason why I wanted  to override this in the first place was to set the correct page name by default. I still have not figured out how to change the title from "Object..." to "TabPage...", though.

```
    protected override object CreateInstance(Type itemType)
    {
        var instance = base.CreateInstance(itemType) as TabPage;

        var control = Context?.Instance as MyTabControl;
        int currentIndex = control.TabPages.Count;
        instance.Text = $"Page {currentIndex}";

        return instance;
    }
```